# C++ standard proposal code: what are N and P?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, iso

What do "N" and "P" in the codes of the proposals to the C++ standard mean?

[Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) is the list of GCC's standard support status. You can see the proposals are like "P0245R1" or "N4051", etc. (The "R", I assume, means "revision").

Comment: "P" - proposal maybe?

Comment: @VTT I thought it means "proposal", but that interpretation leaves no room for "N"..

Comment: *"Technical contributions to be discussed in committee are written up as N-numbered papers."* [Source](https://isocpp.org/std/meetings-and-participation/papers-and-mailings). So I guess it just stands for "Number"?

Comment: Howefer, that would raise the question what the difference between a proposal and an N-paper is to begin with.

Comment: N-numbers indicate official ISO documents and must follow formal ISO rules for format and distribution. P-numbers are not regulated by ISO.

Comment: I speculate that **N** derives from **NP** (new work item proposal) and **P** from **PWI** (preliminary work item) as shown in [ISO/IEC Acronym Summary](http://metadata-standards.org/acronym_summary.html), but I don't have evidence to prove it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From [SD-7: Mailing Procedures and How to Write Papers](https://isocpp.org/std/standing-documents/sd-7-mailing-procedures-and-how-to-write-papers):

> Meeting announcements, minutes, working drafts, editor’s reports, and official document submissions (CD, PDTS, etc.), and records of response must use N numbers.
>
> All other documents should use P numbers.
>
> Documents circulated as drafts should have D numbers (Dxxxx for N documents, and D0xxxRn for P documents).  Only documents for publication should have the N or P numbers.